# php template engine with integrated functions

Tags: php, html

I want to make a php template engine with integrated functions.
e.g.:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<tmp:if {-time-}<"12AM">Good Morning<tmp:else>Good Afternoon</tmp:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Or something like that.
I have alredy made a function that replace {-VAR-} with relative db value but i need some html "functions".

Can you help me?

Comment: BTW, PHP is a template engine

Comment: you dont show a understanding  of the subject you are asking about

Comment: I need an easy template engine for my designer. I know that php is a template engine, but my designer want something different

Comment: Use one of the gazillion template engines that already exist for this purpose? Like Twig or Smarty?

Comment: You will encounter many problems on inventing your own template engine. Charset encoding problems, parse problems, security problems, bad practice design patterns,.... The existing libraries are mature and easy to use, do yourself a favour and don't waste time, money and energy on your own engine. Your boss will thank you, and so will your designer and customers

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into existing templating engines before making your own.

I use [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is also popular choice.

Don't think you need to reinvent the wheel.

You can extend these existing systems to fit your needs.

Comment: i try it, but my designer want something of more easy and specific for his job.

Comment: Designers always want something _easier_. Designers are used to Photoshop. Smarty and Twig are as easy **as possible**. Your own engine will not be easier.

Comment: @Sosh Try Mustache. It doesn't get any more dumbed down than that. If your designer still doesn't like it, kick him. ;)

Comment: Nice thing about established tempting engines is: Robust documentation available. Code completion and highlighting plugins for editors are generally available. If your designer uses netbeans / dreamweaver or something of the like, there should be a plugin available to make his life easier. If you decide to continue and do it yourself, good luck. Much harder task than meets the eye.